# C# - How to parse text file (space delimited numbers)?

Tags: c#, .net, file, string, string-parsing

Given a data file delimited by space,

```
10 10 10 10 222 331 
2 3 3 4 45
4 2 2 4
```

How to read this file and load into an Array

Thank you

Comment: I usually don my monocle and ivory cane when I read in delimited files :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
var array = fileContent.Split((string[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

if you have numbers only and need a list of int as a result, you can do this:

```
var numbers = array.Select(arg => int.Parse(arg)).ToList();
```

Comment: You beat me to it, so I'll post my suggestion here: File.ReadAllLines( "fileName" ).Select( l => l.Split( ' ' ) ).ToArray();

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the kind of array you want. If you want to flatten everything into a single-dimensional array, go with Alex Aza's answer, otherwise, if you want a 2-dimensional array that maps to the lines and elements within the text file:

```
var array = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .Select(line => line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // Use this to filter blank lines.
                .Select(int.Parse) // Assuming you want an int array.
                .ToArray();
```

Be aware that there is no error handling, so if parsing fails, the above code will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You will be interested in [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) and [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get [Quick Joe Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227020/quick-joe-smith)'s answer to work, so I modified it. I put the modified code into a static method within a "FileReader" class:

```
public static double[][] readWhitespaceDelimitedDoubles(string[] input)
{
    double[][] array = input.Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // Use this to filter blank lines.
        .Select(line => line.Split((string[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(line => line.Select(element => double.Parse(element)))
        .Select(line => line.ToArray())
        .ToArray();

        return array;
}
```

For my application, I was parsing for double as opposed to int. To call the code, try using something like this:

```
string[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
double[][] fileContentsArray = FileReader.readWhitespaceDelimitedDoubles(fileContents);

Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows:      {0,3}", fileContentsArray.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Number of Cols:      {0,3}", fileContentsArray[0].Length);
```